# since Aysnc task is depriciated what alternative I can use and how to use

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
class FavouritesFragment : Fragment() {
lateinit var recyclerFavourite:RecyclerView
lateinit var progressLayout:RelativeLayout
lateinit var progressBar:ProgressBar
lateinit var layoutManager:RecyclerView.LayoutManager
lateinit var recyclerAdapter: FavouriteRecyclerAdapter
var dbBookList=listOf<BookEntity>()


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favourites, container, false)
    recyclerFavourite=view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerFavourite)
    progressLayout=view.findViewById(R.id.progressLayout)
    progressBar=view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
    layoutManager=GridLayoutManager(activity as Context,2)
    dbBookList=RetrieveFavourites(activity as Context).execute().get()
    if(activity!=null)
    {
        progressLayout.visibility=View.GONE
        recyclerAdapter= FavouriteRecyclerAdapter(activity as Context,dbBookList)
        recyclerFavourite.adapter=recyclerAdapter
        recyclerFavourite.layoutManager=layoutManager
    }
    return view
}
class RetrieveFavourites(val context: Context):AsyncTask<Void,Void,List<BookEntity>>()
{
    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?): List<BookEntity> {
        val db= Room.databaseBuilder(context,BookDatabase::class.java,"books-db").build()
        return db.bookDao().getAllBooks()
    }

}
```

}

**The above code is used to add a book to the favourites database when button add to favourites is clicked ,now since aysnc task is depriciated how can I change my code to latest please help me**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use coroutines for same since you are already using kotlin

here's a codelab which can help you

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#0

codelab shows similar usecase you have so i don't think i have to post anymore snippets

attaching a short code snippet to show how coroutines work

in onViewCreated

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
  db.bookDao().getAllBooks() 
}
```

in BookDao

use suspend before your getAllBooks() method

```
suspend from getAllBooks(): List<Books>
```

this is all you do.